# how to capture the post call after submitting the form in the website through java

Tags: java, api, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver + java for my web automation.
In a web page, I fill the form and while click submits, say there is one post call goes with url like which can be found through network tab of developer tool of chrome.

```
abc.com/dkplayentryform/latam/gracias.php?uid=&returnUrl=
```

How I can capture this URL through java.
As example go to the https://www.discoverykidsplay.com/enterate
enter the age more than 18 and continue
Then fill the form like first name, last name, email id etc and click submit. Before submitting, enable the developer tool of chrome and you can find there is one post call similar to the above URL. 
I need to capture through java + selenium webdriver
Is it possible?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not a POST call it's a GET call.  Am I wrong?  Request URL:https://tmsdatatool2016.com/dkplayentryform/latam/gracias.php?uid=&returnUrl=
Request Method:GET

Comment: Have you tried the "HttpURLConnection" class?

Comment: Try this:  https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: yes this is GET call. I use HttpURLConnection and io.restassured.RestAssured for api calls in my test suite. But here I need while submit button is clicked what are the urls being called as part of GET method.

Answer (score 0):

There is not straight way to capture the network traffic using webdriver. As a slution you can:

1. Set up [BroswerMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) tool
2. Configure your browser to work thoughout that proxy
3. Introduce the code that reads the requests logged by that proxy (check **Using With Selenium** paragraph).